# How to do something when you lose focus, without onBlur

Tags: reactjs, focus

I have used onBlur to listen on when the input field loses focus. However, this does not work out if the user press "Enter" (And yes, I am handling an Enter event). I've seen onFocusOut, but I dont know how to access this. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: Use the `keycode` ?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you used the `ref` to resolve this issue, but here's working example of thing you're trying to accomplish:

https://codesandbox.io/s/1vzm3x3l44

Answer (score 0):

React uses `onFocus` and `onBlur` instead of `onFocusIn` and `onFocusOut`. All React events are normalized to bubble, so `onFocusIn` and `onFocusOut` are not needed/supported by React

But you can still listen to `focusout`

```
componentDidMount(){
  document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('focusout', handler, false);

  function handler(event) {
    console.log(event.type)
  }
}
```